# GET requests via Python Requests always returns reponse data as Content-Type text/html

Tags: python, python-requests, httpresponse

I am using Python package Requests to perform a `GET` request to a server which returns `json` data in the response. However I can't seem to get the response to form as `application/json` instead of `text/html` as the Content-Type.

```
>>> headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json'}
>>> resp = requests.get("http://192.168.1.180/api/enodeb", headers=headers)
>>> resp.headers
{'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Date': 'Wed, 08 Mar 2017 15:36:16 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}
>>> resp.text
u'<!DOCTYPE html> \n<html lang="en-GB"> \n    <head> \n        <title>Raemis Enterprise</title> \n        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/javascript/jquery.mobile-1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />\n        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jqm-docs.css"/>\n        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/omc.css"/>\n        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>\n        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery.mobile-1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>\n        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery-validation-1.9.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>\n        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery.blockUI.min.js"></script>\n\n        <script type="text/javascript"> \n            function blockui (msg) {\n                $.blockUI({ \n                    message: \'<p><img src="/images/busy.gif" /> \' + msg + \'</p>\'\n                });\n            }\n            function unblockui () {\n                $.unblockUI();\n            }\n        </script>\n\n        \n    <script type="text/javascript"> \n        function getCookie(name) \n        {\n            var nameEQ = name + "=";\n            var ca = document.cookie.split(\';\');\n            for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {\n                var c = ca[i];\n                while (c.charAt(0)==\' \') \n                    c = c.substring(1,c.length);\n                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) \n                    return c.substring(c.indexOf(\'=\')+1, c.length);\n            }\n            return null;\n        }\n\n        function get_groupname ()\n        {\n            $.getJSON(\'/api/session?session_id=\' + getCookie(\'SESSIONID_RAEMIS\'), function (data) {\n                unblockui();\n                switch (data[0].groupname)\n                {\n                    case \'root\' :\n                    case \'admin\' :\n                    case \'sysadmin\' :\n                    case \'monitor\' :\n                        self.location = \'/admin\';\n                        break;\n                    case \'enduser\' :\n                        self.location = \'/user\';\n                        break;\n                    default :\n                       $(\'#form_login .error\').html(\'Cannot start application. Unsupported group \' + data[0].groupname);\n                       break;\n                }\n            }).error (function(xhr, status, error) {\n               var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");\n               $(\'#form_login .error\').html(error + \':&nbsp;\' + err.error);\n               unblockui();\n            });\n        }\n\n        function on_form_submit (form) {\n            $(\'#form_login .error\').html(\'\');\n            blockui(\'Logging in...\');\n            $.post(\'/api/session\', $(form).serialize(), function (data) {\n                form.reset();\n                get_groupname();\n            }).error(function(xhr, status, error) { \n               var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");\n               $(\'#form_login .error\').html(error + \':&nbsp;\' + err.error);\n               unblockui();\n            });\n        }\n\n        $(\'#page_login\').live(\'pageinit\', function () {\n            var form = $(\'#form_login\');\n            form.validate({\n                submitHandler: on_form_submit,\n                rules: {\n                    username: {\n                        required: true,\n                        maxlength: 30\n                    },\n                    password: {\n                        required: true,\n                        maxlength: 128\n                    },\n                }\n            });\n        });\n    </script>\n\n    </head> \n\n    <body> \n        \n    <div data-role="page" class="type-interior" data-theme="a" id="page_login">\n        <div class="simplepage">\n            <h1>Raemis Enterprise Login</h1>\n            <img style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 10px;" src="/images/large_brand_logo.png"/>\n            <form action="#" id="form_login">\n                <div class="error" style="height: 50px;"></div>\n                <div data-role="fieldcontain">\n                    <label for="form_login_username">Username:</label>\n                    <input type="text" name="username" id="form_login_username" />\n                </div>\n                <div data-role="fieldcontain">\n                    <label for="form_login_password">Password:</label>\n                    <input type="password" name="password" id="form_login_password" />\n                </div>\n                <div class="transparent">\n                    <button type="submit" id="submit_login">Login</a>\n                </div>\n            </form>\n        </div>\n    <div data-role="footer" class="footer-docs" data-theme="a" style="width: 100%;">\n    <p>Raemis Enterprise vRev. 21820</p>\n</div>  \n\n\n\n    </div>\n\n    </body>\n</html>\n\n\n'
```

Performing the same actions using Postman, a `http` request tool, returns the correct data without having to set any headers at all.

The data should be:

```
[{
"id": 1,
"enb_id": 1,
"oper_state": 2,
"admin_state": 2,
"name": "Airspan eNB",
"tac": 1,
"cell_id": 257,
"location": "site",
"mac": "",
"downlink_bandwidth": 25000,
"uplink_bandwidth": 12500,
"downlink_earfcn": 0,
"uplink_earfcn": 0,
"mimo_group": 0
}]
```

How can I ensure the response data is in `application/json` Content-Type?

Comment: You haven't shown any code for the server, or is it some third party system? Content-Type header also doesn't matter on GET because there is no body.

Comment: What do you see if you open `http://192.168.1.180/api/enodeb` in browser? Maybe you set some specific header or cookie in Postman?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen The server is a third-party api.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Opening that up in a browser serves me the JSON data.

Comment: @Shiri Try setting the useragent.

Comment: @Shiri Look at the raw request in your browser's developer tools and compare it to what you're sending with Python.